リテラルの取り扱い方
Haskellの超初心者です．下記のようなプログラムを作成しました．
data Natnum = Zero | S Natnum  deriving (Eq, Show)
c_1_1 :: Natnum -> Natnum
c_1_1 x1 = S Zero

その後，c_1_1 Zero と行えば S Zero と出ることは確認できます．
しかし，c_1_1 3 とすると，以下のエラーが発生します．
<interactive>:46:7: error:
    • No instance for (Num Natnum) arising from the literal ‘3’
    • In the first argument of ‘c_1_1’, namely ‘3’
      In the expression: c_1_1 3
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = c_1_1 3

Sは後者関数Zeroの後者関数を得られるものと思っているのですが，理解が間違っているのでしょうか．
私なりに理解しようとしたのですが，これはリテラル3がNatnumに無い，ということを言っていると考え，冒頭のプログラムを以下の様にしてみましたが，結果は同じでした．
data Natnum = Zero | Int | S Natnum  deriving (Eq, Show)

リテラルを扱うときには何か特別なことをする必要があるのでしょうか．
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします．
追記
もともとは以下に示すサンプルプログラムを実行しようとしました．
data Natnum = Zero | S Natnum  deriving (Eq, Show)

succ :: Natnum -> Natnum
succ x = S x

u_2_2 :: Natnum -> Natnum -> Natnum
u_2_2 x1 x2 = x2

add :: Natnum -> Natnum -> Natnum
add x Zero = x
add x (S y) = S (add x y)

multi :: Natnum -> Natnum -> Natnum
multi x Zero = Zero
multi x (S y) = add (multi x y) x

foo :: Natnum -> Natnum
foo x = (S . S) x

bar :: Natnum -> Natnum
bar x = multi x x

baz x y = add x y

daz x y = (foo . bar)(baz x y)

dee x y = (bar . foo)(u_2_2 x y)

このプログラムを
dee 2 3

と実行したのですが，前述の様なエラーが出ました．
このため，そもそもこのサンプルがおかしいのではと考えた次第です．

このエラーは型エラーです。関数 c_1_1 の中身は関係なく、関数 c_1_1 の型の引数部分と与えられた引数の型が合わないために起こっています。
お気づきのように、3 という値は Natnum 型ではありません。したがって関数 c_1_1 に渡すことはできません。S Zero や S (S Zero) は Natnum 型なので関数 c_1_1 に渡せます。
なお、その後お試しの
data Natnum = Zero | Int | S Natnum  deriving (Eq, Show)

については、これは Natnum 型に整数を加えているのではなく、Zero などと同列の存在として Int を加えています。つまり S Int などと書けるようになっているだけです。
補足
追記部分につきまして、こちらは dee 2 3 のように関数を呼び出すのが間違っています。
重要な差として、Natnum として型レベルで模倣しようとしている自然数と、2 や 3 と書けるようなプログラムレベルの整数は、別物です。S Zero を 1 のように振る舞わせることはできますが、同じものではありません。区別して考えてください。
したがって dee (S (S Zero)) (S (S (S Zero))) のように Natnum 型の値を渡すのが意図した使い方と思われます。

早速の回答ありがとうございます．
では，3などの数字をNatnumに与えられるようにするには
Natnumをどのように定義すればよいのでしょうか．
そもそもNatnumに数字を入れることはできないものなのでしょうか．

頑張ればできなくはないですが、素朴にはできませんし、普通はしないです。何故そのようなことがしたいのか分かっていなくて、おそらく何か勘違いなさっているのではないかと思っています。XY 問題の FAQ も参考にしつつ、背景事情を教えていただけませんか。

ご丁寧にご回答いただきましてありがとうございます．今回質問させていただいたものはある書籍の解答例に載っていたものでしたが，おそらくその書籍が間違っているものだと思われます．その書籍ではdee 1 2を実行するとリテラルとして6を表示されていました．そもそもその値がそうならない(16になると考えました)のではないかと思い，試しに実行しようとしたら，上記のようなエラーが発生した次第です．その書籍がかなり間違いがあるのかもしれません．出版社に対し，確認したいと思います．いずれにしましても最後までお付き合いいただきましてありがとうございました．

もしかするとその書籍では、instance Num Natnum ほにゃらら〜、のようにして、数のリテラルから Natnum に自動変換されるような実装をしていませんか？　その場合は dee 1 2 のようにしても型チェックが通ります。

instanceという記述は，そのプログラムがけいさいされているじてんではかかれていませんでした．ご助言ありがとうございました．
